# itext hml2pdf : Declaring font with <link> in source html does not work after version 2.1.0

Tags: c#, .net, itext7

I upgraded my iText HTML 2 PDF package from 2.1.0 to 3.0.3 and the font I was using(Roboto) does not work anymore.

Source html:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<style>

    @page {
        size: A4;
        margin-top: 60px;
        margin-bottom: 100px;
    }
    html, body, table {
        color: #222222;
        font-size: 8.0pt;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 500;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            12<br />
            Lane<br />
            W1 111<br />
            United Kingdom<br />
            Tel: +33 555 555 555
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

C#

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var html = File.ReadAllText("C:\\pdf\\test2.html");
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(stream)))
            {
                try
                {
                    var props = new ConverterProperties();
                    HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(html, pdf, props);
                    File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\pdf\\test2.pdf", stream.ToArray());
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Seems like this stopped working with version 2.1.1

Edit: After a closer look, the font is still Roboto, however, the font-weight is wrong. Roboto-Thin is used instead of Roboto-Regular.

Comment: Hi, can you attach a more complete sample to reproduce? How are you referring to your font family in your CSS?

Comment: @AlexeySubach I've updated the sample code.